# CSS Div That Can Shrink When Another Div Animates

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-animate

http://jsfiddle.net/qmmVC/

I have a heading div, and a hidden popup div inside of a container div.

When I click a button, I want to toggle the opacity and width of the popup div so that it expands into place, and I want the heading div to shrink.

Currently, what it is doing, is causing the heading div to drop down below the popup div, into some paragraph text.

How can I constrain the heading div to retain its top/left coordinate, but shrink/expand its width/height?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         body {
             font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
             overflow: hidden;
         }
         #popup {
             position: relative;
             top: -3px;
             background: #e8e8e8;
             margin: 3px 10px;
             padding: 10px;
             width: 250px;
             height: 80px;
             display: none;
             float: right;
             -moz-border-radius: 15px;
             border-radius: 15px;
             border: 1px solid #000;
         }
         #heading {
             position: relative;
             top: -3px;
             font-size: 1.5em;
             min-width: 50px;
             height: auto;
             overflow: auto;
             margin: 3px;
             float: left;
         }
         .button {
             margin: 3px;
             width: 120px;
             height: 40px;
             color: #fff;
             background: #cc0066;
             text-align: center;
             vertical-align: middle;
             line-height: 40px;
             -moz-border-radius: 5px;
             border-radius: 5px;
         }
         .container {
             margin: 3px 3px;
             padding: 5px;
             width: 550px;
             height: 460px;
             border: 1px solid #000;
         }
      </style>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class='container'>
           <div id="popup">Here is a new section that appears</div>
           <div id="heading">This Is Heading Text In Collapsable Div</div>
           <br/>
           <br/>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mattis in magna eu faucibus. Vestibulum vel fringilla diam. Nulla eget posuere massa. Pellentesque fringilla sapien in rutrum gravida. Phasellus sapien ligula, sagittis sed tellus vitae, semper feugiat nulla. In fermentum, elit eget ornare mattis, mi elit pretium arcu, eget cursus augue velit ac leo. In hendrerit justo eu metus adipiscing, sit amet venenatis sem elementum. Vivamus quis turpis sed elit ultrices molestie. Ut tincidunt, felis eget varius elementum, ante dui semper sapien, quis iaculis ligula urna at neque. In euismod, diam ultrices gravida hendrerit, augue mi luctus dolor, non accumsan purus risus non massa. Sed eget elementum odio. Morbi laoreet magna ac purus venenatis porttitor. Donec et augue a lacus consequat eleifend. Sed fringilla magna et posuere auctor. Donec vel hendrerit nibh. In feugiat dapibus risus eu porta.</p>
           <div class="button">Click Me</div>
       </div>
       <script>
           $(".button").click(function() {
               $("#popup").animate({
                   width: "toggle",
                   opacity: "toggle"
               }, "slow");
           });
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe using position:absolute on the #heading div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand what you want but I'll take shot. consider putting the heading and the paragraph text in the same `<div>`, like so:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div id="popup">Here is a new section that appears</div>
    <div>
        <h1>This Is Heading Text In Collapsable Div</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mattis in magna eu faucibus. Vestibulum vel fringilla diam. Nulla eget posuere massa. Pellentesque fringilla sapien in rutrum gravida. Phasellus sapien ligula, sagittis sed tellus vitae, semper feugiat nulla. In fermentum, elit eget ornare mattis, mi elit pretium arcu, eget cursus augue velit ac leo. In hendrerit justo eu metus adipiscing, sit amet venenatis sem elementum. Vivamus quis turpis sed elit ultrices molestie. Ut tincidunt, felis eget varius elementum, ante dui semper sapien, quis iaculis ligula urna at neque. In euismod, diam ultrices gravida hendrerit, augue mi luctus dolor, non accumsan purus risus non massa. Sed eget elementum odio. Morbi laoreet magna ac purus venenatis porttitor. Donec et augue a lacus consequat eleifend. Sed fringilla magna et posuere auctor. Donec vel hendrerit nibh. In feugiat dapibus risus eu porta.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="button">Click Me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your change provided me with the desired reactions.  Still not sure why having the heading text inside of a div element caused the div to relocate below the popup div on animate.

Comment: Well, for one thing, your CSS heading rules may have needed a little poking and prodding. You may want to re-assign the rules back into the (style-less) div I have created, but do it gradually\warily and with no `min-width` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle use toggle class to achieve this.

http://jsfiddle.net/derekstory/qmmVC/1/

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <div id="popup">Here is a new section that appears</div>
        <div id="heading" class="heading1">This Is Heading Text In Collapsable Div</div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mattis in magna eu faucibus. Vestibulum vel fringilla diam. Nulla eget posuere massa. Pellentesque fringilla sapien in rutrum gravida. Phasellus sapien ligula, sagittis sed tellus vitae, semper feugiat nulla. In fermentum, elit eget ornare mattis, mi elit pretium arcu, eget cursus augue velit ac leo. In hendrerit justo eu metus adipiscing, sit amet venenatis sem elementum. Vivamus quis turpis sed elit ultrices molestie. Ut tincidunt, felis eget varius elementum, ante dui semper sapien, quis iaculis ligula urna at neque. In euismod, diam ultrices gravida hendrerit, augue mi luctus dolor, non accumsan purus risus non massa. Sed eget elementum odio. Morbi laoreet magna ac purus venenatis porttitor. Donec et augue a lacus consequat eleifend. Sed fringilla magna et posuere auctor. Donec vel hendrerit nibh. In feugiat dapibus risus eu porta.</p>
        <div class="button">Click Me</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.heading1 {
    position: absolute;

    top: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    min-width: 50px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 3px;
    float: left;
}
.heading2 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    min-width: 50px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 3px;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
```

JS

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    $("#heading").toggleClass('heading2');
    $("#popup").animate({
        width: "toggle",
        opacity: "toggle"
    }, "slow");

});
```